# Wireshark 2.4.x or 2.6.x compilation error in Windows

Tags: cmake, msbuild, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\wireshark` succeeds.

Then building with `msbuild /m /p:Configration=RelWithDebInfo Wireshark.sln` fails after a while with 4 errors like this

```
D:\wireshark\wsutil/file_util.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [D:\wireshark\build_win64_2015_2.6\rawshark.vcxproj]
```

I don't think it's supposed to include that file on Windows at all.
Any hint what might be wrong with my environment?
Older questions hinted that it might be because same source tree is shared between Windows and Linux, but I don't get why that would be a problem with out of source builds. (I am trying that now anyway.)

Comment: According to the [code](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/wsutil/file_util.h#L32), inclusion of `unistd.h` is guarded with `HAVE_UNISTD_H` macro. This macro is set (or not set) during configuration process (when you run `cmake`). It should be message like `-- Looking for unistd.h - not found` in configuration log. Check that you have this message (or opposite one, with "found" verdict).

Comment: I have `unistd.h - not found`, which I think is correct.

Comment: Hmm, looks like something wrong with configuration. Try to remove build directory, and call `cmake` again.

Comment: Recreating the build directory doesn't change anything.

Comment: After the configuration, it should be `config.h` file in the build directory. This file contains definitions of all `HAVE_*_H` macros used in the other code. Check here, whether `HAVE_UNISTD_H` macro is defined or not. Also check, that you **don't have** `config.h` in the **source directory**: it could be resulted from previous in-source build.

Comment: Config.h in *build directory* doesn't have `HAVE_UNISTD_H` defined. *Source directory* did have it. I removed the file and I am now trying to build again.

Comment: Ok, it worked. You should put this in an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: The answer would be "clone repository (into clean directory) and try again." Like cleaning build directory, it is universal cure, which may help in many "strange" situations.